# Properties of concave functions

Tags: functions, inequality

I would appreciate any help or hints in proving this. I believe it derives from the properties of concave functions, but I don't know much about this.

---

1) Let $C \geq 0$ be a constant and $0 \leq x \leq C$. Prove that

$\sqrt[4]{C} - \sqrt[4]{C-x} \leq \sqrt[4]{x}$

2) Follow-up:

For any concave function $f$, is it true that $f(C) - f(C-x) \leq f(x)$?

Comment: This problem seems ill-posed. First it seems you need $C\geq0$ and second you need $x\leq C$.

Comment: @SuzuHirose Point taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result with the roots can be obtained by squaring twice:
$$
\begin{align}
(\sqrt[4]{C-x}+\sqrt[4]{x})^4&=(\sqrt{C-x}+\sqrt{x}+2\sqrt{x(C-x)})^2\\
&\geq(\sqrt{C-x}+\sqrt{x})^2\\
&=C-x+x+2\sqrt{x(C-x)}\\
&\geq C\\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Nice work. Here is a proof of the follow-up: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=151&t=616916.